# SubSonic error: db.tables with a ~ in the name result in a "Character is not valid" error

Tags: subsonic, struct

I renamed a database table and added a ~ character to the table name (my way of notifying it is a `backup` of something). After generating the SubSonic files, my Visual Studio gives a "Character not valid" error on file "AllStructs.vb"

When looking into this file the following line of code was generated;
Public Shared ReadOnly DbTable1~old As String = "dbtable1~old".

I assume this character has to be filtered out of the db.table names when generating the SubSonic names?

Comment: Same problem with db. stored procedures with a ~ in them...

Answer (score 0):

You can use either stripTableText/stripSPText to remove the ~ from the class names or you could use regexReplaceExpression to replace the ~ with a different character.

You need to specify this in your config when generating your classes, see '[Config Options](http://subsonicproject.com/configuration/config-options/)' for more details.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of naming isn't supported with SubSonic (conventions and all). Your best bet is to use includeTableList and excludeTableList (or one of the other options we have):

http://subsonicproject.com/configuration/config-options/

To help you pare out the old stuff.